# Manage Application.Current while all tests are running in Test Project

Tags: c#, wpf, testing, locking, dispatcher

***Introduction of the problem***

There are several issues on this site about the *Application.Current* is null problem when a method/function of test contains Dispatcher usage. First time I just used a simple solution. I just made a getter property to create a `new Application()` to prevent the "*Application.Current* is null problem".

*First part of the problem:*

Application.Current null issue has been solved but *Dispatcher.BeginInvoke* function never called on UI thread and this function threw *InvalidOperationException* with the following message "The calling thread must be STA exception..." I could not understand because this exception usually throw by background thread or task and the solution to the problem of using dispatcher. After this I used the following code before run my tests.

*First implementation:* (A part of the constructor in the test class.)

```
    var waitForApplicationRun = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
       if(Application.Current == null)
             new Application() { ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown };

       Application.Current.Startup += (s, e) => { waitForApplicationRun.SetResult(true); };
       Application.Current.Run();
    });
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
    waitForApplicationRun.Task.Wait();
```

(This is a modified version of a code snippet.)

My test methods used the dispatcher without any exception in my **first test class**.

*Second part of the problem:*

I created multiple classes for my testes and I moved this code snippet to constructor of an ancestor class because i did not want to copy this solution into every test class. So I made a base class with common setup for my tests.
When I tried to run all my tests with multiple classes in my test project, I was shocked because I expected that the tests behavior won't change but Application.Current threw *InvalidOperationException* with the following message: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Finally I solved this problem with lock usage.
I have extended and modified my code with the following snippet:

*Second implementation:* (A part of the base test class.)

```
    private Application getApplication
    {
        get
        {
            if (Application.Current == null) new Application() { ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown };

            return Application.Current;
        }
    }

    private static object locker = new object();

    public BaseTest()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                getApplication.Startup += (s, e) => Monitor.Pulse(locker);
                getApplication.Run();
                Monitor.Wait(locker);
            }
        });

        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
    }
```

After my last solution all tests of classes (in test project) finished without any problem.

Is this an acceptable solution or it seems to hide the problem(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Working is always a positive aspect of any code, in my opinion.
Some teams take a different approach and use of dispatcher is avoided. Others have any code using dispatcher in a stub which can be switched out using ioc for tests.
One of the advantages of MVVM is that you can instantiate a viewmodel for testing without instantiating or even mocking a view. 
Some purists would say if you use dispatcher at all in a viewmodel then you have a view dependency which is bad.

Comment: I use IoC for tests too but I haven't a clue how I should mock or switch out the dispatcher. Unfortunately I have a few viewmodels which contain Dispatcher but my view project and view model project do not refer to each other (thanks to IoC). +1 for correct explanation.

Comment: I don't mean the dispatcher as such, something intended to invoke or run code.  Often the implementation is almost trivial. You pass an action into the thing which is switched out. It often does nothing in test mode but just allows your code to run OK. You will, by definition, be changing something in a view that presumably just isn't there whilst running tests.