# Problems running multiple xunit tests under STA Thread WPF

Tags: wpf, multithreading, xunit

Following on from my experimentation with [xunit wpf tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67332842/wpf-frame-content-is-null-in-unit-test) I have hit an issue when running multiple tests.

The issue is when I am checking `Application.Current.Windows` in my assertions.

### The Code

To replicate the following code will cause the issue:

**TestWindow**

```xml
<Window x:Class="acme.foonav.Issues.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:acme.foonav.Issues"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TestWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Test**

```cs
public class WpfFactIssues
{
    public WpfFactIssues()
    {
        if (Application.Current == null)
        {
            new Application();
        }
    }

    [WpfFact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        TestWindow window = new TestWindow();
        
        Assert.Equal(typeof(TestWindow), Application.Current.Windows[0]?.GetType());
    }
    
    [WpfFact]
    
    public void Test2()
    {
        TestWindow window = new TestWindow();
        
        Assert.Equal(typeof(TestWindow), Application.Current.Windows[0]?.GetType());
    }
}
```

So here, Test1 and Test2 are identical.  I have removed any other logic not required to demonstrate this scenario to focus on the actual issue - and not why would I want to do this!

The purpose of the scenario was to check whether a window was added into the current application's window collection.

We are using [Xunit.StaFact](https://github.com/AArnott/Xunit.StaFact) to manage running on the STA Thread.

### The Issue

If I execute ALL tests (in Rider) then `Test1` will pass, and `Test2` will fail on the assertion.

`System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

However, I can successfully execute `Test1` and `Test2` individually.

When executing, `Test1` will run on say thread id (`Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`) of 20 then `Test2` will execute on.

When `Test2` executes, then `Application.Current` is set to what `Test1` setup.

### What I have tried

Implementing `IDisposable` and trying calling `Application.Current?.Shutdown()` in the desperate attempt to make it work.

```cs
public void Dispose()
{
    if (Application.Current != null)
    {
        ManualResetEventSlim manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    
        Application.Current.Exit += (sender, args) => { manualResetEvent.Set(); };
        Application.Current?.Shutdown();

        manualResetEvent.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));     
    }
}
```

Here the Exit event is never raised.

This will throw a different exception:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain.`

### Help!

Is there a way to work with the `Application` in unit tests when executing lots of methods in the same class?

**Update**

Currently looking at:

[Manage Application.Current while all tests are running in Test Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49456445/manage-application-current-while-all-tests-are-running-in-test-project)

Answer (score 2):

I'll post this on here for now, although it solves the issue, it yields a further issue.

If we implement a dispose pattern on the test class, we can force a shutdown of the application.  This is somewhat slightly crude.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (Application.Current != null)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown(0);
        var result = Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { }, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle).Result;
    }
}
```

However, when the second test runs, the following exception will be thrown:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain.
```

#### Don't try this at home!

So lets have some hacky fun with reflection around the internals of `Application` - to make this work - at least for this scenario:

Let's track our test state around the Application:

```
public static class FooYou
{
    public static bool hasInited = false;
}
```

This all becomes clear when we new up the Application in our test constructor:

```
public WpfFactIssues()
{
    if (Application.Current == null)
    {
        new Application()
        {
            ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown
        };

        if (!FooYou.hasInited)
        {
            FooYou.hasInited = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var appInit = typeof(Application).GetMethod("ApplicationInit", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            appInit.Invoke(null, null);    
        }
    }
}
```

One final change in the dispose implementation - pretend the app wasn't created in this app domain otherwise this causes the `Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain` exception.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (Application.Current != null)
    {
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
        
        Application.Current.Shutdown(0);
        var result = Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { }, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle).Result;

        var appCreated = typeof(Application).GetField("_appCreatedInThisAppDomain", 
            BindingFlags.Static | 
            BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        appCreated.SetValue(null, false);
    }
}
```

Here we are forcing the reinit of the Application - as done by the `Application`'s static initializer.

Of course, this is a hideous abomination of a solution.  It's dirty.  It is of course very susceptible to breaking - never touch a classes privates.

#### A more workable application of helpers

The above is a little crude, so wrapping up to make the tests work without much effort:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace acme.foonav.Fixture
{
    public static class ApplicationState
    {
        private static bool hasApplicationPreviouslyInitialized;

        public static void CreateNew()
        {
            Shutdown();
            if (Application.Current == null)
            {
                new Application()
                {
                    ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown
                };

                if (!hasApplicationPreviouslyInitialized)
                {
                    hasApplicationPreviouslyInitialized = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    var pre = typeof(Application);
                    var clear = pre.GetMethod("ApplicationInit", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                    clear.Invoke(null, null);    
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            if (Application.Current != null)
            {
                Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
                
                Application.Current.Shutdown(0);
                var result = Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { }, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle).Result;

                var appCreated = typeof(Application).GetField("_appCreatedInThisAppDomain", 
                    BindingFlags.Static | 
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                appCreated.SetValue(null, false);
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Base class for tests that need to use Application:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using acme.foonav.Fixture;

namespace acme.foonav
{
    public abstract class ApplicationContextTest : IDisposable
    {
        protected ApplicationContextTest() => ApplicationState.CreateNew();

        public void Dispose() => ApplicationState.Shutdown();

        protected async Task AwaitDispatcher() => await Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => { }, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
    }
}
```

A test file:

```
using System.Windows;
using Xunit;

namespace acme.foonav.Issues
{
    public class WpfFactIssues : ApplicationContextTest
    {
        [WpfFact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            TestWindow window = new TestWindow();
        
            Assert.Equal(typeof(TestWindow), Application.Current.Windows[0]?.GetType());
        }
    
        [WpfFact]
        public void Test2()
        {
            TestWindow window = new TestWindow();
        
            Assert.Equal(typeof(TestWindow), Application.Current.Windows[0]?.GetType());
        }
    }
}
```

And make sure the tests don't execute in parallel:

```
using Xunit;

[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]
```